# How can I filter a git log to only show distinct file names that have been modified but not deleted?

Tags: git

I am attempting to write a git hook which runs a syntax check on files when they are pushed to the server.

I have successfully shown the log with the file names using

> git log --name-only --pretty=format:'%H' --diff-filter=AM

This gives me the log in the following format:

\<\sha-1>

path/to/file

path/to/file2

...

This will give me only the files that have been added or modified.

I would like to take this a step further, and have a log that meets each of the following criteria:

1. Shows all modified files that have not been deleted in later commits.
     ex) I modify a file and commit it then later I git rm that file and commit that. The log output should not show the file because it was deleted in a later commit
2. Shows all of the created files that have not been deleted. ex) I add a file and commit it, then in a later commit I git rm that file. The log output should not show the file because it was deleted in a later commit.
3. Shows modified files in the latest commit only.  ex) I modify a file and commit it. I modify the file again and commit that.  The log output should only show that file  from the most recent commit.

How can i accomplish this without code? i.e.) a command line solution using git or some combination of git and common unix commands.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a list of files that were added or modified since a given revision `rev`,

```
git diff --name-only --diff-filter=AM $rev..
```

should suffice.

If you really need to know the latest non-merge commit that introduced a change for every of these files, then something similar to the following might work, but will be terribly slow.

```
for rev in $(git rev-list --min-parents=1 --max-parents=1 HEAD); do
    echo $rev
    for file in $(git diff --name-only $rev^..$rev); do
        [ -z "$(git log -1 $rev.. -- $file)" ] && echo "$file"
    done
    echo
done
```